# Default parameters for Get in .NET ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm build API for project and have trouble with default parameters for Get actions
this is sample

```
[HttpGet]
//Without =null its not worked same way 
public IEnumerable<UserModel> GetFilter([FromUri]UserFilterListModel filter = null)
{
    var res = repo.GetFilterList(User.AccountId, filter);
    return res.Rows;
}
```

I want to have both routes

```
http://localhost:1532/api/user?generalFilter=Mant&Page=3

http://localhost:1532/api/user
```

First route works fine, but when I exec GET for second, service return

```
<Error><Message>The argument cannot be null</Message></Error>
```

I'm try to implement Get without parameters, but get error about multiple actions for route.

How to get both routes work correctly

PS: im Create own AttributeRouteFactory, maybe root of evil inside it? 
http://pastebin.com/zx1vnNKZ

Comment: I think your problem is not the routing. I think `repo.GetFilterList` dont work if the second parameter is null. But I can't try this at the moment.

Comment: Nope, execution does not reach repo.GetFilterList, anyway it have null handler